# Highlighting control when mouse is over child control

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I have a silverlight templated control that changes opacity when you hover it . However when user points cursor to its child control the effect wores off. I want to have the control highlighted also when the user hovers any child control. I've did the same thing in WinForms by overriding the WndProc method. Is there something similar in silverlight ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post your titles in all uppercase. It's annoying like someone shouting.

Comment: Does the ChildControl have to be clickable? If not, you could set IsHitTestVisible to false.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have not used the correct events to detect the hover, I suspect you are using `MouseMove`.  Instead  Use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events.  An `MouseEnter` event will occur when the mouse moves over the control.  You move the mouse over child controls and you will get no further events.  Then when the mouse moves completely out of your control you will get `MouseLeave`.